# Enviar formulario por correo php

Tags: php, html5, formularios

estoy haciendo una mini web de un menú de un restaurante y tengo un formulario de contacto que quiero que se envíe a mi correo, pero no lo consigo de ninguna manera, en vez de enviar el correo me descarga el fichero en mi máquina, algún consejo??

Aquí está mi código php, en el formulario en action tengo action="correo.php"(el nombre del fichero).

El problema anteriormente mencionado ya se ha solucionado, ahora el problema es que me envía el correo pero no lee correctamente las variables pasadas por el formulario.

```php
<?php
  $name = $_POST['nombre'];
  $apellidos = $POST['apellidos'];
  $mail = $_POST['mail'];
  $phone = $_POST['telefono'];
  $message = $_POST['comentario'];
  $nacionalidad = $_POST['nacionalidad'];
  $provincia = $_POST['provincia'];
  $calle = $_POST['direccion'];
  $puerta = $_POST['puerta'];

  $header = 'From: ' . $mail . "\r\n";
  $header .= "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion() . "\r\n";
  $header .= "Mime-Version: 1.0 \r\n";
  $header .= "Content-Type: text/plain";

  $message = "Este mensaje fue enviado por: " . $name . "  " . $apellidos . " \r\n";
  $message .= "Su email es: " . $mail . " \r\n";
  $message .= "Teléfono de contacto: " . $phone . "\r\n";
  $message .= "Direccion: " . $calle . " Puerta: " . $puerta . "\r\n";
  $message .= "Nacionalidad: "  . $nacionalidad . "\r\n";
  $message .= "Provincia: " . $provincia . "\r\n";
  $message .= "Mensaje: " . $_POST['comentario'] . " \r\n";
  $message .= "Enviado el: " . date('d/m/Y', time());
  $destinatario = 'victorjp999@gmail.com';
  $asunto = 'Formulario cliente';
  $success = mail($destinatario, $asunto, utf8_decode($message), $header);
  
  header("Location:index.html");

?>
```

Código formulario html:

```html
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <form action="correo.php" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
                <div class="container" style="margin-bottom:50px; padding-bottom: 80px;">
                    <div class="row fondoPrincipal">
                        <div class=" col-sm-6 col-md-2 col-xs-12">
                            <p class="text-white">Nombre*</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 fondoPrincipal">
                            <input type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre" required="" value="" placeholder="Ej: Pepito">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                            <p class="text-white">Apellidos*</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class=" col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                            <input type="text" name="apellidos" required="" value="" placeholder="Ej: Los Palotes">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row fondoPrincipal">
                        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                            <p class="text-white">Teléfono*</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                            <input type="number" name="telefono" required="" value="" placeholder="Ej: 686754213">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 align-middle">
                            <p class="text-white">Email*</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                            <input type="email" name="mail" required="" value="" placeholder="Ej: example@gmail.com">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row elemento fondoPrincipal">
                        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                            <p class="text-white">Nacionalidad</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                            <input type="text" name="nacionalidad" value="" placeholder="Ej: Española">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                            <p class="text-white">Provincia</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                            <select name="provincia">
                                <option value="Valencia"> Valencia</option>
                                <option value="Alicante"> Alicante</option>
                                <option value="Castellón"> Castellón</option>
                                <option value="Murcia"> Murcia</option>
                                <option value="Madrid">Madrid</option>
                                <option value="Barcelona">Barcelona</option>
                                <option value="Málaga"> Málaga</option>
                                <option value="Sevilla"> Sevilla</option>
                                <option value="Cádiz">Cádiz</option>
                                <option value="Vizcaya"> Vizcaya</option>
                                <option value="Baleares"> Baleares</option>
                                <option value="La Coruña">La Coruña</option>
                                <option value="Las Palmas">Las Palmas</option>
                                <option value="Asturias">Asturias</option>
                                <option value="Zaragoza">Zaragoza</option>
                                <option value="Tenerife">Tenerife</option>
                                <option value="Pontevedra">Pontevedra</option>
                                <option value="Granada">Granada</option>
                                <option value="Tarragona">Tarragona</option>
                                <option value="Córdoba">Córdoba</option>
                                <option value="Gerona">Gerona</option>
                                <option value="Guipúzcoa">Guipúzcoa</option>
                                <option value="Almería">Almería</option>
                                <option value="Toledo">Toledo</option>
                                <option value="Badajoz">Badajoz</option>
                                <option value="Navarra">Navarra</option>
                                <option value="Jaén">Jaén</option>
                                <option value="Cantabria">Cantabria</option>
                                <option value="Huelva">Huelva</option>
                                <option value="Valladolid">Valladolid</option>
                                <option value="Ciudad Real">Ciudad Real</option>
                                <option value="León">León</option>
                                <option value="Lérida">Lérida</option>
                                <option value="Cáceres">Cáceres</option>
                                <option value="Albacete">Albacete</option>
                                <option value="Burgos">Burgos</option>
                                <option value="Salamanca">Salamanca</option>
                                <option value="Lugo">Lugo</option>
                                <option value="Álava">Álava</option>
                                <option value="La Rioja">La Rioja</option>
                                <option value="Orense">Orense</option>
                                <option value="Guadalajara">Guadalajara</option>
                                <option value="Huesca">Huesca</option>
                                <option value="Cuenca">Cuenca</option>
                                <option value="Zamora">Zamora</option>
                                <option value="Palencia">Palencia</option>
                                <option value="Ávila">Ávila</option>
                                <option value="Segovia">Segovia</option>
                                <option value="Teruel">Teruel</option>
                                <option value="Soria">Soria</option>
                                <option value="Melilla">Melilla</option>
                                <option value="Ceuta">Ceuta</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row elemento fondoPrincipal">
                        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                            <p class="text-white">Calle</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                            <input type="text" name="direccion" value="" placeholder="Ej: Avenida de Denia">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                            <p class="text-white">Puerta</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                            <input type="text" name="puerta" value="" placeholder="Bungalow 16">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row elemento fondoPrincipal">
                        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                            <p class="text-white">Envíanos tu comentario</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row fondoPrincipal">
                        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 pb-5">
                            <textarea class="w-100" name="comentario" cols="42" rows="10"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row pb-3 fondoPrincipal">
                        <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1">
                            <input type="checkbox" required="" name="terminos">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-11 col-sm-11 col-xs-11 checkbox">
                            <span class="text-white pl-2"><small>He leído y acepto las condiciones expuestas en la <a
                                        href="">Política de Privacidad</a> y <a href=""> el Aviso Legal.</a></small>
                            </span>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row pt-2 pb-3 fondoPrincipal">
                        <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-12">
                            <input type="reset" value="Borrar">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-12">
                          <input type="button" onclick="history.back()" name="volver" value="Volver">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-12">
                            <input type="submit" name="enviar" value="Enviar">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
          </form>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">

        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba a cambiar

```
<¿php
```

Por

```
<?php
```

:)

Como recomendación general: cuando todo falle, intenta el típico `echo "hola mundo";` Con esta sencilla prueba, habrías detectado que habías escrito mal la etiqueta de PHP, por eso te descargaba el código en vez de ejecutarlo.

Quítale también el `enctype="text/plain"` de la etiqueta form del HTML y te funcionará. En tal caso, debería ser `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

Comment: Buenas, lo he cambiado y me lo sigue descargando, ¿alguna otra recomendación?

Comment: He conseguido que no se descargue, pero sigue sin enviar el correo, he modificado, gracias.

Comment: Yo recibo el email perfectamente, igual no tienes algún problema en el hosting o se te están yendo a spam

Comment: ya me envía el correo pero no contiene ninguna de las variables que recojo del formulario @David JP

Comment: Modifica la pregunta añadiendo el código de tu formulario, igual es que no coinciden los nombres de los campos en `name="campo"` y `$_POST['campo']`, o usas `method="GET"` en vez de `method="POST"`

Comment: Ya he mofificado la pregunta con el nuevo código, gracias de antemano. @David JP

Comment: Quítale el `enctype="text/plain"` de la etiqueta `form` del HTML y te funcionará. En tal caso, debería ser `enctype="multipart/form-data"`